# node.js inconsistent TCP reply time

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I want to measure how much time it takes for a response to arrive from a web server. I know that, with node, I can't get an *accurate* measure, but I'm rather interested in *consistent* measurements, so I can detect high lag spikes that I had in the past with my hosting provider.

This is the simplified code I wrote for this (ignore those Log calls):

```
var t1, t2;
var socket = new net.Socket();

socket.on("data", function(data) {
    t2 = new Date;
    Log.w("Request time: " + (t2 - t1) + " ms");
});
socket.on("end", function() {
    Log.w("Received FIN");
});
socket.on("close", function() {
    Log.w("Socket closed");
});
socket.setNoDelay(true);

t1 = new Date;
dns.resolve4("some.host", function(err, addresses) {
    t2 = new Date;
    if (err) Log.e(err.toString());
    else {
        Log.d("DNS time: " + (t2-t1) + " ms.");
        socket.connect(80, addresses[0], function() {
            t2 = new Date;
            Log.i("Connection time: " + (t2 - t1) + " ms.");
            Log.d('Connected to ' + socket.remoteAddress);
            t1 = new Date;
            socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: some.host\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n', function() {
                t2 = new Date;
                Log.i("Socket writing time: " + (t2-t1) + " ms.");
                socket.end();
                t1 = new Date;
            });
        });
        t1 = new Date;
    }
});
```

But, there is a strange behavior with this code. When I run it, the time between `socket.write()` and the `data` event is unexpectedly high, around **140ms** more than the real time.
However, and this is what I don't understand, if I call `socket.connect()` again with the same options after the socket is closed, or if I **rerun the script within 5-15 seconds**, I get the correct measurement.
Here is an output example:

```
~/node $ node test.js  
23-3-2015 22:09:19 > DNS time: 12 ms.  
23-3-2015 22:09:19 > Connection time: 23 ms.  
23-3-2015 22:09:19 > Connected to 91.142.222.187  
23-3-2015 22:09:19 > Socket writing time: 6 ms.  
23-3-2015 22:09:20 > Request time: 167 ms  
23-3-2015 22:09:20 > Received FIN  
23-3-2015 22:09:20 > Socket closed   
~/node $ node test.js  
23-3-2015 22:09:24 > DNS time: 12 ms.  
23-3-2015 22:09:25 > Connection time: 23 ms.  
23-3-2015 22:09:25 > Connected to 91.142.222.187  
23-3-2015 22:09:25 > Socket writing time: 6 ms.  
23-3-2015 22:09:25 > Request time: 23 ms  
23-3-2015 22:09:25 > Received FIN  
23-3-2015 22:09:25 > Socket closed
```

This happens in the server running Debian as well as in my computer running Windows 8.1

I could of course just run the test twice every time and take the second value, but it seems a bit like a waste of time, and I would like to know what is happening under the hood, and how to get it working right in one-shot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should just consider times less than 250ms or so as effectively zero since that's around the interval of the TCP timers such as delayed ACK.

Comment: However and if I remember correctly, in this particular case the only thing that could be delayed is the FIN packet since I receive the data reply, as `setNoDelay` is `true`.